# Wrap every element of ngFor inside new container?

Tags: angular, wrapper, ngfor

What I currently have is a parent component that has this template:

```html
<div class="fxcol full-height" [ngStyle]="style">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let container of form.Containers; let i=index">
    <ev-container class="ev-container " [container]="container" [parentForm]="parentForm" [params]="params"></ev-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

And what i want to achieve is every ev-container wrapped with it's next sibiling by div element like this:

```html
<div class="fxcol full-height">
    <ev-container class="ev-container"></ev-container>

    <div class="fxcol full-height">
        <ev-container class="ev-container"></ev-container>

        <div class="fxcol full-height">
            <ev-container class="ev-container"></ev-container>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Is there any known workaround for this issue?

Thank You!

Comment: Create a component that takes an array as input, displays the first element of this array, and then displays itself recursively, passing the tail of the array as input (unless the array has only one element, and thus doesn't have a tail).

Comment: Thanks! I've done as you suggested and it works as I wanted. But now there are some performace issues i have to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt check it but this should work

```
<ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="tpl"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ index: 0, list: form.Containers }">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #tpl let-index="index" let-list="list">
    <div *ngIf="list && list[index]" class="fxcol full-height" [ngStyle]="style">
        <ev-container class="ev-container"
            [container]="form.Containers[index]"
            [parentForm]="parentForm"
            [params]="params">
        </ev-container>
        <ng-container
            [ngTemplateOutlet]="tpl"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ index: index + 1, list: list }">
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```